# Use Multiple Android Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

Anyone can help me to debug where I m going wrong. Test Code may get from:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz1lc03pNQm6Qkw3bE93dWxjdXc/view?usp=sharing

Scenario, I have 3 `activities`
Main, Splash and menu. First I call Splash activity for 5 seconds after 5 seconds I call menu activity its not working from menu I want to call Main activity. If I skip Menu activity than its working fine.

**Splash Activity**

```
public class Splash extends Activity{
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.dj);
        ourSong.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try 
                {
                    sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                Intent start = new Intent("com.example.test.menu");
                startActivity(start);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.release();
        finish();
    }


}
```

**Menu Activity**

```
public class menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[] = {"MainActivity", "example1", "example1", "example1", "example1"}; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese = classes[position];
        try
        {
        Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.test."+cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(menu.this, ourclass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int counter;
    Button add, subtruct;
    TextView textarea;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter = 0 ;
        add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        subtruct = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        textarea = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                textarea.setText("Your total is"+counter);

            }
        });
        subtruct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                textarea.setText("Your total is"+counter);

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code directly here in the question and highlight which part of it is not working for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
Thread timer = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
            Intent start = new Intent("com.example.test.menu");
            startActivity(start);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

Right code:

```
Thread timer = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
            Intent start = new Intent(Splash.this, menu.class);
            startActivity(start);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

Tip: Don't use lowerCase for Class Names